# Converting a list containing both dictionary and string values to numeric dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list (**List_1**) which contains the values from a key:value pair, and some strings. The list looks like this:

```
List_1 = [dict_values([2]), dict_values([54]),dict_values([111]), 'Blah', 'Blah']
```

I would like to create a new dataframe column called **df['List_1']** which is populated by the values in **List_1**. I would then like to convert **df['List_1']** to a numeric data type, and coerce the NA's to become NaN's.

I've tried this:

```
df['List_1'] = List_1
df['List_1']= pd.to_numeric(df['List_1'], errors='coerce')
```

My expected outcome is to have NA's become NaN's, and the dict_values become numeric, however my approach has resulted in the entire column becoming NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your approach and it worked just fine, but you could use:

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('NA', np.nan)
```

Something is wrong with the definition of NA in your dataset, perhaps? Pandas does not handle missing values like R or other languages/packages used for data analysis, so that could possibly be the problem.